# Zend Framework 2 - Database connection

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Trying to wrap my head around the new concepts of Zend Framework 2.0.

I'm trying to connect to a database, and to get that connection in a controller or model.
Nothing fancy, just the pure connection to run queries against.

So this is my current code:

```
//module.config.php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=HOSTNAME,
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
        'username' => 'USERNAME',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=HOSTNAME is missing ' at end ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create db.local.php in your ./config/autoload folder and add the following content

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zenBlog;host=localhost',
    'username'       =>'root',
    'password'      =>'',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
),
),);
```

in your controller `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');`  to access  to database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working!
Could you also tell me how to access this connection to a Model/any other class?

Comment: How would this be modified to contain 2 separate connections, would it be copy the `db` array and `db` entry in `aliases` and just rename them to e.g. `db2`?

Comment: I haven't tried it ,but I think it can be done by copying and renaming  aliases

Answer (score 0):

This is how my local.php in config\autoload\local.php looks like.

```
<?php
return array(
 'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=<dbname>;host=localhost',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => <your password here>,
     'driver_options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
 ),
 ),
'service_manager' => array(
'aliases' => array(
'adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
),
),);
```

Now use this to create a database adapter:

```
$adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('adapter');
```

Create a sql statetment and put in variable $sql.
Now do this:

```
$statement = $adapter->createStatement($sql);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Typo there, I think, should be 'dsn' not 'dbn'